# Diploid cells and number of chromosomes

Tags: cell-biology, homework

I'm struggling to get a hang on this. I'm getting confused by this sentence from one of my tests:

Each human diploid cell has two sex chromosomes and _____ autosomes.

I'm guessing they're meaning 46, but can someone tell me this in another way? Like in a really easy way, so that I can understand it?

Comment: if you think Alissa has answered your question, you can check her answer.

Answer (score 5):

By definition, an autosome is a chromosome that is not a sex chromosome. Therefore, as a human diploid cell has a total of 46 chromosomes, including two sex chromosomes, I guess the answer to your question should be 44. I hope it's clear enough for you. :)

Comment: YES, that definitely cleared things up. I knew something wasn't right. Another one if you are up to it: 

If the normal diploid number of chromosomes in an organism is 8, how many chromosomes are present in each of the daughter cells at the end of meiosis I?

Is the right answer half - 4?

Comment: Yes, the right answer is 4. ;)